# I can't acces the MODEL field on my database relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I can't access my MODEL field in my database

This is the code that I execute:

```
@foreach($clients as client)
    {{$client->dependents->fname}}
    {{$client->dependents->mname}}
    {{$client->dependents->lname}}
@endforeach
```

This code returns an `error` : Property [fname] does not exist on this collection instance.

When I do this code:

```
@foreach($clients as client)
    {{$client->dependents}}
@endforeach
```

This code returns a `successful` array of data.

This is my Client Model:

```
class Client extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [];

    public function dependents() {
        return $this->hasMany(Dependent::class);
    }
}
```

And this is my Dependent Model:

```
class Code extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [];

    public function client()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Client::class);
    }
}
```

How can I retrieve each field using the eloquent model method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is `HasMany` relation AND It returns multiple departments so that `fname` is undefined.  Because it has an object of departments, not the department and you are missing `$` from `@foreach($clients as client)`.

```
@foreach($clients as $client)
 @foreach($clients->dependents as $department)
   {{$dependent->fname}}
   {{$dependent->mname}}
   {{$dependent->lname}}
 @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Try this, It will work for you. Enjoy!

Answer (score 2):

In order to access the fields on dependents model, you need to make a foreach, because the client model **hasMany** dependents and when you try to access simply **$client->dependents->fname** doesn't know which one to access.
So, you need to do the following:

```
@foreach($clients as $client)
    @foreach($client->dependents as $dependent)
       {{$dependent->fname}}
       {{$dependent->mname}}
       {{$dependent->lname}}
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```